# Overloading istream>> to read comma-separated input

Tags: c++, beginner, parsing, stream, overloading

I have the following very simple class:

```cpp
class accusation
{
private:
    std::string murderer;
    std::string weapon;
    std::string place;
public:
    accusation() = default;
    accusation(std::string, std::string, std::string);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const accusation&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, accusation&);
};
```

I have overloaded my extraction from istream operator as follows:

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, accusation& readable)
{
    std::vector<std::string> accusation;
    std::string token, word;
    //divide by commas
    while (std::getline(is, token, ','))
    {
        std::string pushable;
        std::stringstream ss(token);
        while (ss >> word) pushable += word + " ";
        if (pushable.size() != 0) pushable.pop_back(); //remove that last white space
        std::transform(pushable.begin(), pushable.end(), pushable.begin(), ::tolower);
        accusation.push_back(pushable);
    }
    if (accusation.size() == 3)
    {
        is.clear();
        bool valid{ false };
        //check it matches one of the clue::characters
        for (const auto& character : clue::characters)
            if (accusation[0] == character)
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        if (valid)
        {
            valid = false;
            //check it matches one of the clue::weapons
            for (const auto& weapon : clue::weapons)
                if (accusation[1] == weapon)
                {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (valid)
            {
                valid = false;
                //check it matches one of the clue::places
                for (const auto& place : clue::places)
                    if (accusation[2] == place)
                    {
                        valid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if (valid)
                {
                    readable.murderer = accusation[0];
                    readable.weapon = accusation[1];
                    readable.place = accusation[2];
                }
                else
                    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            }
            else
                is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
        else
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    else
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

I am reading input as `green, dagger, kitchen` and storing it in my accusation. The first element has to be in `clue::characters` (an array of possible game characters), second element in `clue::weapons`, and third element in `clue::places`.

Can somebody suggest a cleaner way to overload this operator? The code works as expected, but I believe that there is **a lot** of space for improvements. Any push into the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CR, Could you please change the title to show the requirement from business/exercise point of view rather than your concerns. Concerns should go into the body of the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

95 percent of programming is looking for redundancies and eliminating them.

For example, why do you bother with reading strings into `accusations[]` first, and then *later* copying them into `readable.murderer` et cetera? Why not just read them directly into `readable.murderer`? This would have the bonus of eliminating those "magic number" indices 0, 1, and 2, and replacing them with readable (no pun intended) identifiers.

```
std::getline(is, readable.murderer, ',');
std::getline(is, readable.weapon, ',');
std::getline(is, readable.place, ',');  // shouldn't this last one be '\n' not ','?
```

You should test your code and see if it does what you wanted.

```
std::istringstream iss(
    "Mr Green, lead pipe, conservatory\n"
    "Mrs Peacock, noose, kitchen"
);
accusation acc;
iss >> acc;
```

This reads 5 items into `accusation`. Is this what you wanted to happen?

---

Reduce repetition. You have the following snippet repeated three times:

```
    for (const auto& THING : THINGS)
        if (accusation[INDEX] == THING)
        {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
```

So, first of all, we wrap the loop body in curly braces to protect against [goto fail](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/); and then we factor it out into a function.

```
template<class T>
bool vector_contains(const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {
    for (auto&& elt : vec) {
        if (elt == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then our main function's code can become simply

```
bool valid = vector_contains(clue::characters, readable.murderer)
          && vector_contains(clue::weapons, readable.weapon)
          && vector_contains(clue::places, readable.place);
if (!valid) {
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}
```

---

The body of `vector_contains` could also be implemented simply by using an STL algorithm, e.g.

```
template<class T>
bool vector_contains(const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {
    return std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
bool vector_contains(const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {
    return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value) != vec.end();
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
bool vector_contains(const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {
    return std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const auto& elt) {
        return elt == value;
    });
}
```

I named the function `vector_contains`, rather than simply `contains`, because in my estimation there is a very real possibility that C++2a might add `std::contains` to the library [and thus break any code using ADL calls to `contains`.](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/17/std-size/)

---

Minor nits:

- I strongly recommend making all your constructors `explicit`, to eliminate bugs from unintentional implicit conversions. (Yes, even your multi-argument constructors.)
- I strongly recommend making `operator>>` and `operator<<` into *inline* friend functions — define them right inside the body of your class. This will make them findable only via ADL, and is generally what you want. It'll look a lot more reasonable, too, once you've refactored your `operator>>` to be only five or six lines long! :)

---

You're also doing something weird with `stringstream` to remove whitespace from the ends of each piece of the string. You should factor that out into a helper function, and then simplify it. Say,

```
std::string strip(const std::string& s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (isspace(s[i])) ++i;
    int j = s.size();
    while (j >= 1 && isspace(s[j-1])) --j;
    return s.substr(i, j-i);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/uVSolN0Nepk48Mgm

```
class accusation
{
private:
    std::string murderer;
    std::string weapon;
    std::string place;
public:
    accusation() = default;
    explicit accusation(std::string, std::string, std::string);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const accusation&);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, accusation& a) {
        std::getline(is, a.murderer, ',');
        std::getline(is, a.weapon, ',');
        std::getline(is, a.place);
        if (!vector_contains(clue::characters, a.murderer) ||
            !vector_contains(clue::weapons, a.weapon) ||
            !vector_contains(clue::places, a.place)) {
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
        return is;
    }
};
```

Deciding whether your `std::transform` lowercasing should be removed, kept, or folded into the helper function `vector_contains` (renaming that function to indicate its new purpose, and using a non-mutating facility such as `strcasecmp`) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, it has been very eye-opening reading all your suggestions. Regarding your 'strip' function, it only removes white spaces from the beginning and the end of a string; opposed to what I was doing which deleted extra white space between words as well. Nevertheless I get your point, and will improve my code from all your suggestions.

Comment: Given that you made `mr  green` acceptable as a synonym for `Mr Green`, maybe you should consider whether `mrgreen` should be acceptable as well. Then you wouldn't even need to remove spaces; you could just write a non-mutating string comparison, similar to `strcasecmp`, that ignores all whitespace too. Personally, I would go the other direction and force the user to enter `Mr Green` using that one exact spelling, to increase simplicity and ease-of-teaching-the-interface. If you do want to do clever fuzzy matching, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching for ideas.

Comment: Writing directly into the object means you lose the strong exception guarantee. You also risk creating invalid `accusation` objects with broken invariants. Writing into a temp object then moving into `a`, or, even better, writing into three strings then doing validation on them (using a function you should already have for validating the constructor args), is a better plan.